# Classic VM migration to Resource In azure

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am looking to migrate my existing Classic Azure VM to Resource VM. Is there any tool available to do that??

Or Help me by providing suitable link to do same.

Comment: all it takes is 10 seconds of googling. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview

Comment: I already gone through this link but its useless or only theory. However, I am looking for a tool @BrunoFaria

Comment: Check next steps in that link. All you need is Powershell.